# How to copy value from request into response in Azure API management policy

Tags: azure-api-management

In APIM policy, I wish to copy value from request body in inbound policy to response body in outbound policy.

Is there a concept of global variable in APIM policies?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a variable.

Policy:

```
        <policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <set-variable name="requestBody" value="@(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true))" />
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <!-- Unused for this sample 
            <base />
            -->
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
            <set-body template="none">@{
                // var responseBodyFromBackend = ((IResponse)context.Response).Body.As<string>(true); 
                var requestBody = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<JObject>("requestBody");     
                var response = new JObject();
                response["OriginalRequestBody"] = requestBody;
                return response.ToString();        
            }</set-body>
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>
```

Request Body:

```
{
   "hello": "world"
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
    "OriginalRequestBody": {
        "hello": "world"
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives syntax errors if you use <, > inside value string. Use encoded xml values for symbols as per this link. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Comment: @shehanpathi I'm not able to reproduce your issue. If I copy the entire `policy`, APIM saves it without any error messages. Did you change anything?

Comment: I had to change ```<JObject>``` to xml encoded string -> ```&lt;JObject&gt;```. Otherwise it gives me xml parsing errors in VS editor.